# How can I parse parse date with time and miliseconds in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, datetime-parsing

I want to convert a datestring into another date format.

### The datestring

```
2014-11-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

### The code

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

### The error

```
time data '2014-11-20T00:00:00.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'
```

I can read the error message but I cannot find the right format that matches the datestring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the millisecond paramater use this: `datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ').strftime('%Y%m%d')`